# how to name a file with a string in c++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to name my file after a user input.

for example: application asks for name. User types in test and the file is called "test.txt".

My code:

```
using namespace std;

string filename;

cout << "name? "; cin >> filename;
ofstream outfile(filename + ".txt");
outfile.close();
```

I programmed with Java before, so maybe its the problem :)

EDIT:
Maybe the whole code helps more:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

long double fac(long double num){
    long double result= 1.0;
    for(long double i=2.0; i<num; i++){
        result *=i;
    }
    return result;
}
int main(){
    long double z;
    string q;
    string filename;
    long double pi=0.0;
    for(long double k=0.0;k<10.0;k++){
        pi += (pow(-1.0,k) * fac(6.0 * k) * (13591409.0 + (545140134.0 * k))) / (fac(3.0 * k) * pow(fac(k), 3.0) * pow(640320.0, 3.0 * k + 3.0/2.0));
    }
    pi *= 12.0;
    cout << "Wie viele Nachkomma-Stellen? "; cin >> z;
    cout << setprecision(z+1) << 1.0/pi << endl;
    cout <<"Als Datei schreiben? [(Y)es/(N)o]"; cin >> q;
    if(q=="Y" or q=="Yes" or q=="y" or q=="yes"){
        cout << "Dateiname? "; cin >> filename;
        ofstream outfile(filename + ".txt");
        outfile << setprecision(z+1) << 1.0/pi << endl;
        outfile.close();
        cout << "Als" + filename + ".txt  gespeichert";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to compute pi. Its my first project on C++. So its nothing special, but i want to learn the basics, like my problem now.

compiler tell me:

```
g++ -Wall -c "test.cpp" (in directory: /home/christian/Documents/Programmierung/Programme/Test)
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:32:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char>)’
   ofstream outfile(filename + ".txt");
                                     ^
test.cpp:32:37: note: candidates are:
In file included from test.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:640:7: note: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       basic_ofstream(const char* __s,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:640:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:625:7: note: std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
       basic_ofstream(): __ostream_type(), _M_filebuf()
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:625:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:599:11: note: std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char>&)
     class basic_ofstream : public basic_ostream<_CharT,_Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:599:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const std::basic_ofstream<char>&’
Compilation failed.
```

thanks for helpful answers

Comment: This looks almost exactly like a previous question. `ofstream` constructor may not take `std::string`, so you need to use `.c_str()`. But note: if the file name has an extension, this will just add `.txt` to the end of that.

Comment: @crashmstr It can in C++11. Otherwise `(filename + ".txt").c_str()`

Comment: You also need to specify exactly what isn't working right: if you get a compile-time error, please include it, and mark which line it occurs on. If you get a runtime behavioral problem, indicate exactly what happens and what you want to happen instead.

Comment: Loop over a `long double` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: `string.c_str(filename);` is completely wrong. `c_str` takes no parameters and is used for its return value. You should look up the documentation or work from a tutorial/book/class/etc.

Comment: i used a long double, because with the other types my pi isnt long enaugh. And It shouldn't be a professional program. just to learn some basics.

Comment: string.c_str(filename) wasnt my purpose. I corrected it. just forgot to update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a C++ dialect older than C++11, and so you can't pass an `std::string` to the `std::ofstream` constructor; it's just not supported until C++11.  However, you can pass a `char const *`, and the `std::string::c_str()` method will return a pointer that is appropriate to use here:

```
// Creates a temporary std::string and calls c_str() on it, passing the result to
// the std::ofstream constructor.
ofstream outfile((filename + ".txt").c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks it heped me now. I am a total beginner. Just have a few knowledge in Java. So I dont really know it. Thanks a lot